# Can devpi-server be used to create groups?

Tags: usergroups, devpi

Devpi's docs for the `--restrict-modify` param specify that in addition to specifying access rights for a user, access rights can also be modified for a group:

> specify which users/groups may create other users and their indices. Multiple users and groups are separated by commas. Groups need to be prefixed with a colon like this: ':group'. [...]

There's no documentation about how to actually *create* a group, though; is this integrated directly with the Unix groups available on the host machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `devpi` server does not do any group management itself. Instead, it delegates it to the auth plugins. Take a look at the [`devpiserver_auth_user`](https://github.com/devpi/devpi/blob/master/server/devpi_server/hookspecs.py#L77) hookspec:

> return dict containing authentication validation results.
>   A dict must be returned with a key "status" with one of the following values:
>
> - "ok" - authentication succeeded
> - "unknown" - no matching user, other plugins are tried
> - "reject" - invalid password, authentication stops
>
> Optionally the plugin can return a list of group names the user is member of using the "groups" key of the result dict.

AFAIK currently there is only plugin using groups: [`devpi-ldap`](https://github.com/devpi/devpi-ldap), [check out its code for usage example](https://github.com/devpi/devpi-ldap/blob/master/devpi_ldap/main.py#L246).

As for binding the access rights to unix groups, you could easily write such an auth plugin yourself. Here is a dumb example of a plugin that does not do any real auth, only returning the unix groups the user requesting access belongs to:

```python
# myplugin.py

import grp
from pluggy import HookimplMarker


@hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def devpiserver_auth_user(userdict, username, password):
    # get all groups for the user
    groups = [group.gr_name for group in grp.getgrall() if username in group.gr_mem]
    return {'status': 'ok', 'groups': groups}
```

Now add `devpi`'s entry point in the plugin's setup script and you're good to go:

```python
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='devpi-unix-group-auth',
    py_modules=['myplugin'],
    entry_points={
    'console_scripts': {
        'devpi_server': ['devpi-unix-group-auth = myplugin']
    },
    ...
)
```